# py2app + email_to (gmail) = ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email_to'

Tags: email, smtplib, py2app

I tried to make a `*.app` file that uses the `email_to` library, analogous to `smtplib + email.mime` (I tried it before, but there is more code, and the error is exactly the same).
If you create a `*.app` file that sends a letter, then it does not work, although the `*.py` of this project itself fulfills its task!
I decided to go the other way and create a second `**.py` program which I turned into `**.app` using the `py2app` library; contents of `**.py`:

```
from os import system, getcwd

if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        system("git clone https://github.com/syroiezhin/console2app")
        system("python3 carrier.py") # carrier.py == *.py
        system(f"rm -rf {getcwd()}")
    except: pass
```

As a result, a copy of the `*.py` repository is created inside the `**.app` project, which it launches itself, and after execution it will delete it. But, unfortunately, one error pops up, which I mentioned at the beginning, which could not be solved, I already tried:

0. I tried to add libraries in setup.py in setup(`install_requires=['email_to']`) and also list packages in 'packages': ['email_to'] in OPTIONS. I did not see the expected result, the error continues to torment me.
1. Tried `os.system("pip email_to")` in `*.py`, which will load and run, and that didn't work either;
2. Tried a similar way with `smtplib + email.mime`;
3. I tried to install via `os.system` - `pip`, but he continues to swear at me;
4. Tried to run `**.app` file without `email_to` package in `*.py` - it works without errors;
5. Tried to run the `*.py` file where it is without running the `**.app` file, going inside, and it works without errors;
6. Tried to run `**.py` file without building `**.app` for it, and it works too;
7. When I run the `*.py` file via the launch of `**.app`, in which the command `system("python3 carrier.py")` is written, it constantly writes the same error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email_to'

The problem arises precisely in including libraries so that `*.py` can use them after copying the repository inside the `**.app` file. Indicates an error at the call site `from email_to import Message, EmailServer`. **What are some ideas for a solution?**

Comment: Please write your question in English, as [Stack Overflow is an English only site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676). There are other versions of Stack Overflow in [Português](//pt.stackoverflow.com), [Español](//es.stackoverflow.com), [русский](//ru.stackoverflow.com), and [日本語](//ja.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

the question with the `email_to` package remains open.
but i managed to create an app file without the same error with `smtplib + email.mime` libraries!!!

I don’t know what exactly could affect from everything I did, so I will list what I did:

1. in the terminal I updated the anaconda that I use:

```
conda update --force conda
conda update anaconda
conda update conda
```

2. updated separately py2app and the setuptool adjacent to it:

```
conda uninstall setuptools
conda install setuptools
conda update --force conda
```

3. updated this element, which sometimes cursed me:

```
conda remove zeromq
conda install zeromq
```

4. I also added this, since it stopped working for some reason, sometimes I use it to test the sketch:

```
conda install jupyter
```

5. I also went through [this article](https://www.macports.org/install.php).
   Reinstalled the `smtplib + email.mime` libraries and it suddenly started working. Exemple:

```
sudo port search email
```